# Value changes when manipulating subclass by their superclass

Tags: d

I'm encoutering a strange problem.
When passing a subclass to a method accepting a superclass, which is ok because subclass is a superclass, variables of the subclass seems to change ...
With a more explicit example :

```
import std.stdio;

void main () {
    SuperClass myspc = new SuperClass();
    showSupID(myspc); // shows 0, ok

    SubClass mysbc = new SubClass();
    showSupID(mysbc); // shows 0 again, wtf ?

    showSubID(mysbc); // shows 3, ok
}

class SuperClass {
    int id;
}

class SubClass : SuperClass {
    int id = 3;
}

void showSupID(SuperClass object){
    writeln(object.id);
}

void showSubID(SubClass object){ // I want to avoid to have subclass specific methods
    writeln(object.id);
}
```

In my code I want to centralize an action for all kind of subclasses by using their relationship with their superclass. This strange behavior is a big problem for me.

**Did I forgot something ? Where is the problem ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are not polymorphic. `SuperClass` has a variable named `id`, and `SubClass` has a different variable named `id`, and as `SubClass` is derived from `SuperClass`, it also has access to `SuperClass`' `id`, but only if it explicitly accesses it (e.g. via `super.id` in code inside of `SubClass`). And as `id` is not polymorphic, which `id` you get when accessing it depends on the type of the reference used to access it. If the reference is of type `SuperClass`, then it's `SuperClass`' `id` which is accessed, whereas if the reference is of type `SubClass`, then it's `SubClass`' `id` which is accessed.

If you want polymorphic behavior, you have to use a `public` or `protected` function. Variables are never polymorphic.

Comment: let me also mention the [@property](http://dlang.org/property.html) attribute, which seems to belong here as well :)